# Does reading what you listen parallely improve your ability to speak English?

Tags: language, learning, cognitive-science

I can write English well, and can also understand it well (provided someone speaks i a known accent.)

For improving my spoken English I have got audio books. I can understand what I am being told by the book.

There are many claims on the internet that reading while listening improves your language skills, for example:

> **Read and listen simultaneously**
>
> Reading text yourself while you listen to someone speak can prove to be a great strategy for improving your pronunciation. You can instantly pronounce exactly the way you hear the other person speak and also read the text so you remember how to pronounce those words in the future.

([How to Improve Your English Pronunciation](http://www.omniglot.com/language/articles/improveenglishpronunciation.htm))

From - http://successfulenglish.com/2010/01/the-power-of-reading-and-listening/

> Read and listen at the same time. There are benefits to seeing and hearing new language at the same time.

In the above link they are talking about the fluency of spoken English.

so, I if read the book parallely while listening to the same, is my **spoken (ability to speak)** English going to be improved?

Comment: This might better be asked in the English Language Learners section.

Comment: I think it has a place here. I know several people (myself included) that at least *feel* they're learning faster if they watch TV/movies with subtitles, for instance.

Comment: I find that I don't listen much when there are subtitles as I concentrate on that rather than on the talk.

Comment: Have added a new claim in the question body.

Comment: I find it unlikely that one and the same method is best for all students.  Will it work for you?  Try it and see.

Comment: Define, "speak". Clearly, it will help you learn to enunciate your words correctly, as you imitate what you hear.

Comment: It definitely helped me with learning foreign languages. But I wouldn't say it improves ability to speak, but listening comprehension and writing.

Comment: wouldn't this entirely depend on how well the speaker pronounces/enunciates when [s]he is reading aloud?